# Use image maps to show and hide div elements

Tags: jquery, html, imagemap

This is my code so far..

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/moragw5/vr6wzuc2/)

I'm wanting the user to be shown the blue text only if they click the blue circle etc...

I guess I just have to change the attributes of the div elements but I'm not very comfortable with jQuery and unsure of the most elegant way to do this.

HTML

```
<img src="http://www.j-creative.biz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/primary-colours-300x171.png" usemap="#test1" alt="" />
<map id="primarytest" name="test1">
  <area shape="circle" coords="50,75,50" href="#" item="red"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="150,75,50" href="#" item="blue"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="250,75,50" href="#" item="yellow"/> 
</map>

<div class="one" style="display:none" id="redtext">
<h5>
HelloRed
</h5>
</div>
<div class="one" style="display:none" id="bluetext">
<h5>
HelloBlue
</h5>
</div>
<div style="display:none" id="yellowtext">
<h5>
HelloYellow
</h5>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('[item="red"]).click(function() {
$(".one").hide();
    $("#redtext").show();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is just missing a closing quote on the selector and jQuery from the fiddle. Fix those issues and it works:

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/w9d9mae2/)

That being said, you can improve the logic by following DRY principles. To do this you can put a common class on the `area` elements as well as a `data` attribute to specify which element they should show when clicked on. You can then use a single event handler on all of them. Try this:

```
<img src="http://www.j-creative.biz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/primary-colours-300x171.png" usemap="#test1" alt="" />
<map id="primarytest" name="test1">
    <area shape="circle" coords="50,75,50" href="#" class="circle" data-target="redtext" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="150,75,50" href="#" class="circle" data-target="bluetext" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="250,75,50" href="#" class="circle" data-target="yellowtext" />
</map>

<div class="one" id="redtext">
    <h5>HelloRed</h5>
</div>
<div class="one" id="bluetext">
    <h5>HelloBlue</h5>
</div>
<div class="one" id="yellowtext">
    <h5>HelloYellow</h5>
</div>
```

```js
$('.circle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".one").hide().filter('#' + $(this).data('target')).show();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vr6wzuc2/1/)